# Unable to calculate percent of column total in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a simple measure that represents a countries sales as a percentage of total sales. I first created a Slicer on the page so the user can filter to a specific country. I then wanted to use the sales of the filtered country as the numerator, and for the denominator using the ALL function remove all filters so it sums the grand total. The idea is I would then represent the data for each store (rows) to see how that store performs

However, when I do this all I see is 100% for every row when I run the report.

How can I make sure the numerator and denominator correctly understand the context / filters when doing their calculation.

```
Test Performance Variance = 
VAR __BASELINE_VALUE = SUM('Test'[Sales])
VAR __VALUE_TO_COMPARE = SUM('Test'[Sales])
RETURN
    IF(
        NOT ISBLANK(__VALUE_TO_COMPARE),
        DIVIDE(__VALUE_TO_COMPARE, 
            CALCULATE( __BASELINE_VALUE,ALL(Test[Country])))
    )
```

Desired result is this:

```
Store | Sales | Performance
ABC   | 15    | 15%
DEF   | 65    | 65%
GHI   | 20    | 20%
```

But instead I am seeing:

```
Store | Sales | Performance
ABC   | 15    | 100%
DEF   | 65    | 100%
GHI   | 20    | 100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a constant (the `VAR` you defined) within a `CALCULATE`, so the `ALL` doesn't do anything because a constant is fixed and doesn't change with the filter context.

Try rewriting the measure like this:

```
Test Performance Variance =
VAR __BASELINE_VALUE = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Test'[Sales] ), ALL ( Test[Country] ) )
VAR __VALUE_TO_COMPARE = SUM ( 'Test'[Sales] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( __VALUE_TO_COMPARE ),
        DIVIDE ( __VALUE_TO_COMPARE, __BASELINE_VALUE )
    )
```